# Javascript Grid with multiple groupings

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, grouping, multi-level

I would like to know if there are other javascript components that provide presentation of grid with multiple groupings. Below is a screenshot of [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) I extended to allow the feature however it needs all the data to be fetched. I would like that data would be loaded when the grouping is expanded.

[image: Screenshot of jqGrid]
Another modified jqGrid would be nice since it is what we've been using in our project :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net) does this really well.

The tutorial on how to do the show/hide details is [here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html)

I strongly recommend Datatables because after trying nearly every jQuery and YUI solution out there I've realized that it has more features, better support, and the best Ajax operation I've found.  As a strong bonus, it's ThemeRoller capable, which means that I can re-skin my apps in just minutes, which has made that operation incredibly profitable.

Comment: will check it out :). for the mean time, I just used tree grid since I'm out of time >.< (p.s. says needs 15 rep when I click the up button o_o)

Comment: Datatables has no real grouping feature. What you linked is a row details feature.

Answer (score 2):

ShieldUI's Grid can also do this - it has flexible [grouping](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-grouping/grouping), [hierarchy support](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/hierarchy) and and many other fancy options.

It is a very affordable solution compared to others and also comes with a whole library of other useful UI widgets for charting, editing, layout, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I know one free component that is similar to the above described grid - [TreeTable](http://webix.com/widget/treetable/). It provides presentation of grid with multiple groupings: http://docs.webix.com/samples/15_datatable/30_treetable/14_colspan.html. Moreover, it has a dynamic loading feature.